# AVL tree Rotation problems

Tags: c, avl-tree, tree-rotation

I've been facing a very weird problem with an AVL tree implementation. Given the code below, I can only run it with no right rotations, since that if I do, I have a crash. I already tried debugging, deleting files and remaking the project, and rebuild, none of this worked.

In advance, I apologize if the code is a little hard to understand, I'm brazilian and the variable names are mostly in Portuguese, if that proves to be a problem in helping the problem, I'll change the variable names to english.

`avl.h` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct avl{
    int elemento;
    struct avl *esq;
    struct avl *dir;
    int altura;
}avl;

avl *novo_no(int);
avl *rotacao_dir(avl *);
avl *rotacao_esq(avl *);
avl *insercao_avl(avl *, int);
int calcula_fb(avl *);
int max(int, int);
int get_altura(avl *);
void in_order(avl *);
```

`avl.c` file:

```
#include "avl_tree.h"

//creates a new node with the given integer
avl *novo_no(int elemento){
    avl *novo = (avl *)malloc(sizeof(avl));
    if(novo){
        novo->elemento = elemento;
        novo->dir = NULL;
        novo->esq = NULL;
        novo->altura = 1;
        return novo;
    }else
        exit(1);
}

//right rotation
avl *rotacao_dir(avl *arv){

    avl *filho_esq = arv->esq;
    avl *subarvore_dir = filho_esq->dir;

    filho_esq->dir = arv;
    arv->esq = subarvore_dir;

    //updates the height

    arv->altura = max(get_altura(arv->esq), get_altura(arv->dir)) + 1;
    filho_esq->altura = max(get_altura(filho_esq->esq), get_altura(filho_esq->dir)) + 1;
    //printf("Altura de [%d]: %d\n\n", filho_esq->elemento, filho_esq->altura); //debug print of the node and it's height

    return filho_esq;
}

//left rotation
avl *rotacao_esq(avl *arv){
    avl *filho_dir = arv->dir;
    avl *subarvore_esq = filho_dir->esq;

    filho_dir->esq = arv;
    arv->dir = subarvore_esq;

    //updates the height

    arv->altura = max(get_altura(arv->esq), get_altura(arv->dir)) + 1;
    filho_dir->altura = max(get_altura(filho_dir->esq), get_altura(filho_dir->dir)) + 1;
    printf("Altura de [%d]: %d", filho_dir->elemento, filho_dir->altura);

    return filho_dir;
}

//insertion
avl *insercao_avl(avl *arv, int elemento){

    /*1. BST normal insertion*/

    if(arv == NULL) return novo_no(elemento);

    avl *aux = arv;
    if(elemento <= aux->elemento)
        aux->esq = insercao_avl(aux->esq, elemento);
    else
        aux->dir = insercao_avl(aux->dir, elemento);

    //Inicia os testes para as rotacoes

    /*2. updates height */
    arv->altura = max(get_altura(arv->esq), get_altura(arv->dir)) + 1;

    /*3. get the balance*/
    int fb = calcula_fb(arv);
    printf("FB do no[%d] = %d\n",arv->elemento, fb);

    //If unbalanced node, 1 of the 4 following cases will apply:

    //3.1 esq->esq
    if (fb > 1 && elemento < arv->esq->elemento)
        return rotacao_dir(arv);

    //3.2 dir->dir
    else if (fb < -1 && elemento > arv->dir->elemento)
        return rotacao_dir(arv);

    //3.3 esq->dir
    else if (fb > 1 && elemento > arv->esq->elemento){
        arv->esq =  rotacao_dir(arv->esq);
        return rotacao_dir(arv);
    }

    //3.4 dir->esq
    else if (fb < -1 && elemento < arv->dir->elemento){
        arv->dir = rotacao_dir(arv->dir);
        return rotacao_dir(arv);
    }

    /*4. Returns node */
    return arv;
}

//gets the balancing factor of a node
int calcula_fb(avl *arv){
    if(arv == NULL) return 0;
    else return(get_altura(arv->esq) - get_altura(arv->dir));
}


//get max between 2 values
int max(int a, int b){
    return((a > b) ? a : b);
}

//get a node's height
int get_altura(avl *arv){
    if(arv == NULL) return 0;
    else return arv->altura;
}

// in-order travel of the tree
void in_order(avl *arv){
    if(arv == NULL) // se arvore vazia então finaliza
        return;

    in_order(arv->esq); // chamada recursiva para a subarvore esquerda
    printf("[ %2d ] ", arv->elemento); // visita a raiz
    in_order(arv->dir); // chamada recursiva para a subarvore direita
}
```

`main.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "avl_tree.h"

int main(){

    avl *raiz;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        raiz = insercao_avl(raiz, i);

    in_order(raiz);


    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, my right and left rotation functions(`rotaciona_dir` and `rotaciona_esq` respectively) are basically mirrors, so bugs me that the right one doesn't work. I've trying different calls, and right now I"m just using a `for` loop for testing. If I make my input be decreasing, all works fine, but as soon as I need to call the `rotaciona_dir` function, the program crashes.

On note about the IDE/compiler, I'm using Code-Blocks IDE 13.12, in a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system.

Also, any code improvement or general programming tips are welcome. I'm not much a C programmer myself(Python is my main language), so the answer for this may be very simple and I'm just not getting it.

Comment: None of your four cases 3.1 to 3.4 call `rotacao_esq`. They all call `rotacao_dir`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: oh my...That was it...I feel stupid. Looks like I was using auto-complete too much.

Comment: How should I mark this as solved? since your answer came in the comments, should I just delete it(the question)?

Comment: You can post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Looks like I used auto-complete a little bit too much. None of my cases were calling `rotacao_esq`, my left rotation function, and that was making the code malfunction. Lesson learned. Marking this questions as solved. Thanks to all who helped and special thanks to @IanAbbott for point that newbie mistake.